# Any idea why hyperlinks to same page anchors stopped working in my markdown file posted as a gist

Tags: github, markdown

I regularly share markdown pages with my collaborators by uploading them to gist. I usually include a "table of contents" at top with hyperlinks to headers in the page. The hyperlinks are just anchors named after the content of the headings. This worked fine until a few days ago. The anchors are there, you can see them in the page source and they are rendered. Clicking on the links brings you to the right URL (with the anchor in it). But the page doesn't move. Tried this on several browsers.

Here's an example page at https://gist.github.com/ho-ben/a3eaf926f6a91611d575b0256316afe6#more-stuff

Comment: That is strange. I don’t see any obvious problems. I wonder if GitHub disabled the functionality with some JavaScript or something.